# Filter not working on function returned values

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-filters

I'm using angular's currency filter. It doesn't seem to filter for a data that is returned from a function. I think I'm missing something. Could be when the filter gets digested?

Here's snippets of my code:

html template file

```
<span>total: {{ vm.total.exgst | currency}}<span>
```

controller.js for the html template

```
var calculateTotalExGST = function() { return _.sum(vm.items, function(item)
                                                   { return item.cost; });
                                      };
vm.total = { exgst: calculateTotalExGST() };
```

So somehow the html displays

> total: 5

But it should display as $5.00. The value gets returned but the function but the filter doesn't work. Could it be something to do when $digest happens?

Can anyone help me explain?

**edit:**
Bit more information about the code, `vm.items` are values from `$state` of ui-router.

I'm not sure how to get all of that into jsfiddler. So i've just mocked $state.
But i can't replicate my issue unfortunately.

https://jsfiddle.net/ex5rj9u7/

Comment: Prepare a codepen/jsfiddle which shows your problem, please.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are using the wrong method. From the Lodash doc, `sum` is used just for arrays. You are looking for the `sumBy` method.

Take a look at this example: https://jsfiddle.net/relferreira/dng7s3qs/

**JS:**

```
angular.module('app', []);

angular.module('app')
    .controller('MainController', mainController);

mainController.$inject = ['$scope'];

function mainController($scope){

    var vm = this;

  vm.items = [
    { cost: 5},
    { cost: 5}
  ];

    var calculateTotalExGST = function() { 
    return _.sumBy(vm.items, function(item){ 
        return item.cost; 
    });
  };

  console.log(calculateTotalExGST())

    vm.total = { exgst: calculateTotalExGST() };


}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div data-ng-app="app">

  <section ng-controller="MainController as mainVm">
    <span>total: {{ mainVm.total.exgst | currency}}</span>
  </section>

</div>
```

Comment: You would be correct with using sumBy, but the version I'm running with is 3.10 (which sum is sumBy). 

The summation works but not the filtering.

Comment: Ok. but I posted a working example. Take a look at it to see what is wrong with your code. Look if there isn't any JS error in your console. When I copied your code, there was a syntax error in you calculateTotalExGST function.